# When the form is empty, pressing the Login button opens the page. I have to make a mistake

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, authentication

When the form is empty, pressing the Login button opens the page. I want him to make a mistake. I'm already getting an error if it's not compatible with the server. How can I solve this problem ?

```
const login = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    axiox.post("http://localhost:2000/api/auth/login", {
        email,
        password
    }).then((response) => {
        console.log("response", response)
        localStorage.setItem("login", JSON.stringify({
            userLogin: true,
            token: response.data.access_token,
        }));
        setError("");
        setEmail("");
        setPassword("");
        history.push("schools");
    })
    .catch((error) => setError(error.response.data.message));
    
};
```

Comment: Try to validate the form

Answer (score 0):

use this to validate the form

```
const login = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if(!email || !password){
     //send error message to user  
     }else{
       // make request to api
     }

};
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple and efficient way is to check any errors at the client-side i.e if the form is empty you should not make an API call. The validation on the form or in your function to check if the values are `null` is enough.

You can add more validations on the form, however, certain validations which are business mandate could be done at the server-side.

```
const login = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
       // make request to api
   if(!email && !password) { 
      //here make the API call to authenticate a user  
   }

};
```

Check [this](https://www.pragimtech.com/blog/reactjs/Validate-forms-in-react/) link to get more details, how to add the validation in React Forms.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want the form to respond with an error message when they haven't filled up the form. Here:

```
const login = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if(!email || !password){
     //Send the error message, like alert('Either the Email or Password is empty!') 
     }else{
       //The code to execute when both Email and Password are filled.
     }
};
```